# How to convert cucumber gherkin feature files into JSON or AST format?

Tags: node.js, abstract-syntax-tree, gherkin, cucumberjs

I am working in a project where i need to understand gherkin parsing better than ever. Also need to implement certain higher order functionalities based on content.

I wanted to know how to convert cucumber gherkin feature files into JSON or to get it into AST Tree. I tried using [Gherkin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gherkin) package from npm repo but i am not able to get the stream out into json with all the content. Can someone help me with an example or sample code to extract a feature step to AST or JSON format. Please help..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Gherkin documentation, you can use the Gherkin CLI to produce an AST as a JSON object. There are plenty of [examples of the output and command-line parameters on their GitHub repository](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/tree/master/gherkin#ast). Since you are parsing Gherkin, which is programming language-agnostic, you can use whichever implementation of Gherkin you prefer.

Comment: Yes @steven agreed with the examples but i want to design a function which could take a feature file and output corresponding json from it. wanted some example code for the same. the existing documentation doesn't provide any such scenario.

Comment: I was doing it wrong. Thanks for the answer. I figured out a way to do it with cucumbers native parsing as well :)

Comment: @SiddharthMishra Would you add the way you found as an answer, please?

Comment: @avidD use this document to get feature as json out[ut to stdout - https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/main/docs/formatters.md. Hope this helps